# How to find CName/canonical name using DNS in swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, cname

How to find CName/canonical name using DNS in swift 4, currently I am using shell command "NSlookup" to find Cname which works fine but parsing string is little clumsy, So I wanted to know if there is some clean and better way to find cName.

I also tried using "gethostbyname". I was trying to check if the struct output of gethostbyname contain h_name but getting this error:

"dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:5 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted"

while fetching "gethostbyname".

```
    var hostinfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<hostent>
    let hostString: String = "example.com"
    let hostname = (hostString.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8))!
    hostinfo = gethostbyname(hostname)
```

please let me know if there is any better way to find CName/canonical name.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused by having SANDBOX turned on. Toggle Sandbox support in project settings, Targets -> Capabilities -> App Sandbox.